# Update Navigation Drawer content Value get Activity is not recognized

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I have Navigation drawer using recyclerview with some static text. I wish to update level value at end of the static text from SharedPreferences which holds a integer value. I'm using the recyclerview for my navigaton Drawer.

**NavigationAdapter.java**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            final int i) {

            Drawable drawable = null;
            if (mData.get(i).getDrawable() != 0) {
                drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                        mData.get(i).getDrawable());
            }

            if (mData.get(i).getType() == NavItem.ITEM) {
                setText(viewHolder.textViewItem,viewHolder.textViewlevel, i, drawable);
                setBackgroundColor(i, viewHolder);
            }
}
private void setText(TextView textView,TextView textViewlevel, final int i, Drawable drawable) {
         SharedPreferences sharedPref= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("levels", 0);
            String level_time= sharedPref.getString("level_time", "");
        textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());
        textViewlevel.setText(level_time);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null,
                null);
}
```

SharedPreferences is not working and giving me error at "getActivity().getSharedPreferences("levels", 0);"
Is there any other way so that I can access SharedPreferences ?

Comment: instead of 0 use Context.ModePrivate.

Comment: @SurenderKumar I tried and that too same kinda error, check here http://prntscr.com/6b8s7n

Comment: can you tell me what the actually error is coming

Comment: get Activity() is not recognised, please check the two files NavigationFragment.java and NavigationAdapter.java pastebin.com/3EpSgbS0 and pastebin.com/jKrAsztZ  here in the Navigation Adapter getActivity() is not recognised. check the screenshot.prntscr.com/6b8s7n

Comment: then change the getActivity() with your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getActivity() isn't recognized inside your recycler-view's adapter. You can define the adapter as an inner class of your fragment. Other wise, pass context to your adapter's constructor and use it:

```
public class Adapter extends .... {

    private Context mPassedContext;

    public Adapter(Context con, ....) {
        mPasssedContext = con;
    }
}
```

Use this context:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref= mPassedContext.getSharedPreferences("levels", 0);
```

Comment: your answer sounds right but app get crashed with error"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity "  Here are the two files Navigation Fragment.java and NavigationAdapter.java please check it our. http://pastebin.com/3EpSgbS0 and http://pastebin.com/jKrAsztZ

Comment: @Vrangle please change public NavDrawerAdapter(List<NavItem> data, NavDrawerFragment context) ==>> public NavDrawerAdapter(List<NavItem> data, Context context) and call the contructor this way ==>> NavDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(NavItems, getActivity());

Comment: @Vrangle accordingly, `private NavDrawerFragment mContext;` in NavDrawerAdapter will be changed to ==>> private Context mContext;

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String channel = shared.getString(keyname, "");
```

Here you have used the   0 instead of  MODE_PRIVATE